# How to model partnership?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I would like to model the partnership between two persons. My first idea was to use an Association. The ends of the Association must be named differently. Therefore I would need two roles: `partner1` and `partner2`. This in turn allows each person to have two partners. Not exactly what I wanted.
[image: partnership]
My second try is to use an attribute `partner`. Here the problem is, that the partner of one person's partner should be this person, but the model doesn't capture this. Of course we could use a constraint with this effect, but I would prefer a solution with graphical notation.

The third option (suggested in a comment below) uses an additional Class `Partnership`. This works, but if it doesn't have any attributes, it just makes the model more complicated than necessary.

The most elegant solution would be an Association where both `member ends` would be the same `partner` Property. However this is not allowed, since the member end property is unique. Therefore it can't contain the same property twice. Is this a bug in the specification? Is this really such a rare case? It happens with all recursive Associations, where the role is the same on both sides.

Comment: I assume you want to avoid an additional class called `Partnership` to solve it?

Comment: Such a class would be necessary, if the Partnership needs additional attributes. But without it, I consider it a workaround.

Comment: Oh, I see that I gave that as answer - lol

Comment: Well, the problem is in this case it's the simplest solution. Alternative would be constraints, not very elegant but can work as well.

Comment: @ThomasKilian no problem. It's more important to have the correct answer not who gave it ;-)

Comment: the best solution is probably a directional relation 'partner' with the constraint _self.partner.partner = self_

Comment: I voted to close this as opinion based since you did not define "Partnership" in a way a valid answer is possible.

Comment: I agree that the original question is opinion based, since the current specification obviously doesn’t allow a satisfactory answer (which I somehow expected, but couldn’t believe. After all, is this really such an unusual request?). Maybe I should rephrase it to ask for the best way to creatively stretch the UML specification.

Comment: Yes, that would probably put it into the right light. I had been thinking about that aspect but now it's just too early to answer ;-). However, instead of modifying this one you should ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of a symmetric partial association. Such an association can only be modeled with the help of a suitable constraint, as shown in the following model:

[image]

The attached explicit constraint/invariant can only be avoided if a corresponding constraint keyword to be used in an association stereotype like "symmetrical" would have been defined. Unfortunately, UML 2.5 doesn't provide such a stereotype, but we are free to add it like so:

[image]

[I've only read the comment by "bruno" above after submiting my answer. "bruno" correctly pointed out the need for the main part of the constraint: `self.partner.partner = self`.]

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem. However, it needs a Constraint for a case that is usually modeled by the Association. An Association between wife and husband automatically means that self.wife.husband=self. No need for a Constraint. Why do we have to add a Constraint, just because we found out, that any two Persons can form a Partnership. My gut feeling is, that the UML specification should be enhanced to cover this case.

Comment: No, it's not true that "an association between wife and husband automatically means that self.wife.husband=self". Each person could have both a wife and a husband! You ALWAYS need a constraint for enforcing such additional requirements. In the case of husband-wife you can enforce this with a constraint that requires that a husband is male and a wife is female.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that two new Classes are needed: `Man` and `Woman`. Only a `Man` can be a husband and only a `Woman` can be a wife. My main point is, that the constraint implied here should also be implied in the partner-case. Do you think, the Association between the `partner` attribute and itself I proposed above would do the job?

Comment: Of course, modeling such an association between two (disjoint) classes is a different problem from modeling it as a recursive association (where the range is the same as the domain class). Your Option 2 is pretty much the same as my model, but you would have to add the constraint! As I already said: you don't get a symmetric partial recursive association without a suitable constraint!

Comment: LOL (of topic): of course this ancient constraint is no longer valid world wide (has it ever been?). Homosexual marriage is possible...

Answer (score 0):

How about this construct: [image]?

A couple has exactly 2 persons linked. A class must not have any extra properties. However, you could think of the date when it was created. In case of a marriage the person giving the family name could be indicated, etc. There's probably more about that partnership as you seem to have a need for it.

Now, why did I use the composite aggregation? Basically a composition means that dissolving the composing element will also eliminate the composed ones. So this looks quite catholic, doesn't it? Yes, and shame on me. However, there should be something expressing "person can only be composed for one couple". And that's what composite aggregation also tells (on my favorite page 110):

> Composite aggregation is a strong form of aggregation that requires a part object be included in at most one composite object at a time. If a composite object is deleted, all of its part instances that are objects are deleted with it.

Well, so instead the shared composition should be used

> Indicates that the Property has shared aggregation semantics. Precise semantics of shared aggregation varies by application area and modeler.

with a modeling explanation that explains that each element must only be used once in a shared composition.

Of course a simple association with a constraint would be best. I'll leave the diagram this way, though, for the readers amusement.

P.S. Reading through the various comments makes me think that the semantics of `Partnership` (and it brotherhood variants) are by far more social sensitive than one intuitively starts to think of. So the real "answer" should be: define the social context for `Partnership` first.

Comment: I wouldn't use composition in this case. A person can be involved in multiple relationships, and if the relationship end the involved people usually survive. Other than then I definitely recommend a class like `Couple` or `Relationship`. This entity can have it's own data such as `legal status`, `start date` etc...

Comment: @GeertBellekens Well, from me as a non-composite fighter that will mean something using it. I'll should have given some explanation... will do now.

Comment: An Aggregation could be used here, but since it doesn't have any semantics, it is just a matter of taste. A Composition is not necessary, because the fact that one `Person` can only be part of one `Couple` is given by the multiplicity. It could be useful, when our system also contains a `Friarhood` and we want to express, that an Instance of `Person` can either be part of a `Couple` or of a `Friarhood`. But then, as you said, the deletion semantics would probably not be intended.

Comment: Yeah. Actually I dislike any kind of the diamond notation. It always comes to nasty discussions. Constraints on associations work much better. I guess you mean `Brotherhood`? If so you would just set the multiplicity to `2..*`.

Comment: I was talking about the multiplicity on the `Brother/Friarhood` side. It would be 0..1, as on the `Partnership` side. Since I assume, that the brothers live in celibacy, a `Person` cannot be in both a `Partnership` and a `Brotherhood`, something that is expressed by a Composition. I agree, that in this case Constraints are the better choice.

Answer (score -2):

The elegant solution mentioned in the question would look like this:
[image: Person with partner attribute]
It doesn't look much different from other solutions, but is actually not possible with the current UML, since the member end property has `isUnique=true`:
[image: Metamodel]
I think, this is a bug of the specification. It certainly can get corrected (shown in blue). However, it seems this bug has not been noticed very often. Would this correction be useful enough to be worth the effort?

Should this answer be upvoted, I will file an issue.

Comment: Not sure if self-reference allows identical role names on both sides. Unfortunately that means: UML crunch for dinner :-/ Filing a bug with OMG will put it in a long list. I have one which is a couple of years old.

Comment: I don't see what "non unique" would help. There's only ìsUnique` as constraint and it not being present means "not necessarily unique". Only adding `isUnique` seems meaningful (to me). Referring to the same property twice feels schizophrenic.

Comment: Your "solution" is hardly elegant, but rather non-sensical! What is it supposed to mean in terms of a mapping to OOP classes or to formal logic (e.g., OWL)?

Comment: The string “non unique” is the notation for `isUnique=false`. I agree that it sounds schizophrenic, but it would allow to model that both member ends of the Association refer to the same property. I’m not sure, what the mapping to OWL would be. A mapping to OOP is anyway not possible, since bidirectional Associations are not OO. However, it means that two instances of `Person` have a Slot for `partner` that is constrained to `self.partner.partner=self`, the same way as an Instance of `Woman` is constrained to `self.husband.wife=self`. This looks for me like the analogous situation.

Comment: Thinking once more, your suggestion looks reasonable (OTOH it's late too...). The role names refer to instance properties (although you did not set the owned property dot). However, that can make sense even in OWL view. But it still does not solve the constraint which Bruno suggested.

Comment: Ah, no. If there's a relation between exactly two you have a 1--1 multi and the 1--(0..1) is just nonsense. Better I sleep over this :-)

Comment: @ Axel Scheithauer: What do you mean with "A mapping to OOP is anyway not possible, since bidirectional Associations are not OO"? Of course, we can represent/implement bidirectional associations with OOP in the form of a pair of mutually inverse reference properties (like Person::husband and Person::wife). But your model cannot be mapped to OOP because it has no clear meaning!

Comment: Usually an Association contains three statements. Since in this case only one property is involved, it contains only two: 1) Each instance of Person can have 0..1 partners of type Person. 2) The slots on both sides of the link typed by the Association are filled by the instances on the opposite sides. This is exactly what I wanted to express.

Comment: @GerdWagner: Associations imply constraints, that object oriented languages usually don't imply. Of course, we can manually add behavior that makes sure that the constraint is fulfilled. For a bidirectional Association it is not defined who is reponsible for hosting this behavior, but in OO an object is supposed to have clear responsibilities. Therefore, I think that bidirectional Associations are not object oriented.

Comment: For any association modeled in a UML class diagram there is a well-defined mapping to OOP classes, including its multiplicity constraints, which can be implemented by corresponding checks in CRUD operations. The fact that for your funny model there is no such mapping shows that your model is meaningless.

Comment: @GerdWagner: There is a well defined mapping to an object oriented language:`class Person {partner: Person;  setPartner(p:Partner){self.partner =p; self.partner.partner=self} }`. This is completely analogous to `class Woman {husband:Man; setHusband(h:Man){self.husband=h;self.husband.wife=self;}}` and `class Man {wife:Woman; setWife(w:Woman){self.wife=w;self.wife.husband=self;}}`. The assumption is, that the attributes without visibility marker are visible for classes in the same package and that Man and Woman are in the same package.

Comment: Your mapping is the mapping for my model (with a symmetricity constraint, but without duplication of association end names). If your model gas the same mapping, this means your duplicate association end name is meaningless.

Comment: My model uses the mapping defined for all bidirectional Associations. No additional mapping rules are needed. Your model needs a developer, who manually adds behavior to fulfill the textual constraint. It could be possible to create such a behavior automatically, but in general this is not a trivial problem.

Comment: In case you think, that the _names_ are the same on both sides. This is not about names, it is about the _Properties_ being the same on both sides. There are three possibilities for Associations: They can specify links between two instances of two different Classes in two different roles, or the same Class in two different roles, or the same Class in the same role. The latter is currently not allowed by the specification. I don't see why.